# Modify Evaluation in Weka

Tags: java, classification, weka

Is there a way to post-process the Weka Evaluation predictions generated by `Evaluation.evaluateModel()`? for example to change the predicted value for a certain instance?
Unfortunately the Prediction-object does not have setters.. so I tried overwriting of the `NominalPrediction`.
But the default-constructor is requiring the distribution.. So I think that is a misleading attempt doing this.

Comment: A solution to this can be achieved by performing the evaluation of your model manually using for e.g n-fold cross validation

Comment: How do you mean this?... I am now adding a prediction for each Instance manually using Evaluation.evaluateModelOnce(predictedValue, Instance).. The FP-rate,FN-rate etc. is generated as usual.. But measures like the AUC are zero.. Is it possible to get a "full" evaluation like the ones i get if i call .evaluateModel()?

Comment: You don't have to use Evaluation. Just use `trainCV` and `testCV` methods to split instances for your folds. Then create your classifier model and then use `classifyInstance` method to classify Instances. You can manually count corrects, predicted and reals and then calculate precision, recall or whatever values you are interested in